# How to write a Crystal reports formula comparing string to number field

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, formula

I have three fields. Two of the fields I want to compare to each other to make sure that they equal each other. If they don't equal I want another field within the report to display 'ERROR' instead of the Serial number that it's supposed to display if the first two fields are equal to each other.

I want to compare these two fields

{V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.WORKORDER_ID}) &  {WORKORDER.FG_LOTNO}

And if they equal to each other I want 
{V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.CSERIAL} to display else if they don't equal I want it to display "ERROR' in the {V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.CSERIAL} field.

Crystal Reports 2013

So, I had something like this as my formula but even though both fields are string fields it's asking for a number via an error for the {WORKORDER.FG_LOTNO} field when I check the formula for correctness.

if({V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.WORKORDER_ID}) = {WORKORDER.FG_LOTNO} then 
  {V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.CSERIAL}
else
  'ERROR'

Want to display an error on the report if the fields do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if({V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.WORKORDER_ID}) = {WORKORDER.FG_LOTNO} then {V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.CSERIAL} else 'ERROR'
```

to

```
if({V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.WORKORDER_ID} = {WORKORDER.FG_LOTNO}) then {V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.CSERIAL} else 'ERROR'
```

Comment: Did you intend to use double quotes around ERROR in your modified formula?  As its written now, I see no difference between your suggested formula and Todd's formula.

Comment: The original enclosing of ({V_LMINVTRY_MANUFACTURED.WORKORDER_ID})  in parentheses caught my eye as something that doesn't serve any purpose, so I moved the closing to the end of the condition. But you are right that this wouldn't make a difference in this case. 
Just posted a second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if WorkOrder_ID field is actually numeric. If it is, you can either convert FG_LotNo to numeric or change the WorkOrder_ID to text using type conversion functions.